# XSLT use child elements names as table headers

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xalan

im new in xsl and I have some xml files with similar structure, like this:

```
 <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS Records</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
```

and other similar but with title and number of songs as description of the cd

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Eros</title>
        <number_of_songs>12</number_of_songs>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>One</title>
        <number_of_songs>12</number_of_songs>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

What I need is to make an xsl file for all the xml, to make a table and takes the names of the child elements of cd, put them as  and for each cd a row with the description. 
Like this:

║ Title      ║Number of songs

║ Eros           ║12

║ One ║12

cant post images yet:(

So far i've done this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table style="border:2px solid #24343A; border-radius: 4px;">
                    <tr bgcolor="#4488A5" style="color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">

                        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd/child::*">
                            <th> <xsl:value-of select ="local-name()"/></th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                        <tr bgcolor="#8DC1D7" style="color:#21323B;">
                            <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
                                <td> <xsl:value-of select ="child::*"/></td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesnt work, i get the header, but it repeats many times, and cant get the value
Thanks

Comment: What do you need the first XML for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off. Two things:

- you don't want the headers to repeat - you only want the element names of the first CD, so the first expression becomes `catalog/cd[1]/*` (child::* can be replaced with *)
- you want the text content for each value, not the child element. So use text() rather than child::*

See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table style="border:2px solid #24343A; border-radius: 4px;">
                    <tr bgcolor="#4488A5" style="color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">
                        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[1]/*">
                            <th> <xsl:value-of select ="local-name()"/></th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                        <tr bgcolor="#8DC1D7" style="color:#21323B;">
                            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                                <td> <xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but `child::*` can *always* be replaced with `*`, not only in this case. ;-)

Comment: This still gives a false impression of `local-name()`. "In this case", `name()` should be used.

Comment: You're correct about `child::*`, I was confused about the child axis versus element (`child::*`) or node (`child::node()`) children.

Comment: Using name() rather than local-name() outputs the namespace prefix when it is present, if the stylesheet used name() then `<x:title xmlns:x="http://foobar/">Empire Burlesque</x:title>` would give a table header of `x:title` which is probably not what the author wanted. But using the xml element name as human-readable text is not a very flexible option either - better to define table headers separately in the input xml.

Answer (score 2):

Use the stylesheet below. I'd also recommend you study it closely.

Note that

- you should avoid using `xsl:for-each` whenever inappropriate. Instead, use `appyl-templates` and write separate templates that match the elements concerned.
- It is not clear whether you want to transform the first XML file you have shown. To arrive at your output, it is not needed.
- `local-name()` makes sense only where elements have *namespaces*. To simply retrieve the name of an element, use `name()`.

**EDIT** Modified stylesheet, suggested by @Tomalak.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table style="border:2px solid #24343A; border-radius: 4px;">
              <tr>
                 <th>Title</th>
                 <th>Number of songs</th>
              </tr>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cd">
  <tr bgcolor="#4488A5" style="color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="title|number_of_songs" />
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="title|number_of_songs">
  <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </td>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table style="border:2px solid #24343A; border-radius: 4px;">
     <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Number of songs</th>
     </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#4488A5" style="color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">
        <td>Eros</td>
        <td>12</td>
     </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#4488A5" style="color:#ffffff; text-align:center;">
        <td>One</td>
        <td>12</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Output in Firefox**

[image]

---

**A possible enhancement**

Your attempted XSLT  retrieves the names of the header columns from the XML file. This is a proper way to do this:

```
 <tr>
   <th>
      <xsl:value-of select="name(cd[1]/title)"/>
   </th>
   <th>
      <xsl:value-of select="name(cd[1]/number_of_songs)"/>
   </th>
 </tr>
```

However, this copies the exact name of elements. So, in HTML, your column headers will be lowercased and the second one will look like: `number_of_songs`.

Comment: Your stylesheet should either do `<xsl:apply-templates select="title|number_of_songs" />` (instead of the unspecific `<xsl:apply-templates/>`) or contain `<xsl:template match="*" />` to suppess unwanted output.

Comment: Also, `cd[1]/title/name()` does not work (`name()` is a function, not a node test). Correct would be `name(cd[1]/title)` - which, unsurprisingly, outputs `'title'`, so that you could just as well hard-code the desired string there. Outputting the `name()` of a node only makes sense if you don't already know it, like in a multi-purpose template.

Comment: Did you test this? I did, and it works as I intended.

Comment: Yes, I tested this. `cd[1]/title/name()` isn't valid XPath. What XSLT processor do you use for testing?

Comment: I'm not questioning your authority, but this works in my stylesheet. I get `<th>title</th>` as output. (Of course, you can hard-code it if you know it beforehand, that's what I did in my answer. I added it just as extra info, since the OP appeared to be trying this).

Comment: Thanks for the tips they were very useful.

Comment: `some/path/name()` is valid XPath 2.0 but not 1.0 - in 1.0 you need `name(some/path)` instead.  If you're writing a 1.0 stylesheet you need to test it on a 1.0 processor...

Comment: With so many comments already I hesitate whether to add this, but anyway:"*you should avoid using `xsl:for-each` whenever possible.*"  This should read: *you should avoid using `xsl:for-each` whenever inappropriate*. `xsl:for-each` is not a second-class tool.